# Unable to install tensorflow_federated in venv

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-federated

Trying to install tensorflow_federated in venv. But it always gives an error

```
stating
subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

This is the error statement

 Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\AML_Lear\aml\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>        
          main()
        File "C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\AML_Lear\aml\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\AML_Lear\aml\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4bm49dlc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4bm49dlc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4bm49dlc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup        
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4bm49dlc\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup        
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn2Kx.png)

tried to resolve it by Updating Python to 3.11.3 and pip to 23.1.2, deleted the venc then again created new venv, also updated setuptools and also installed ez_setup but none of that helps and still unable to install tensorflow_federated.

OS: Windows 11
Editor: VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow federated requires: `Python >=3.9.0, <3.11` which is causing above error as you have installed `python version 3.11`

Please try again installing `TF Federated` package after downgrading python version to `3.10` or `3.9`.

```
pip install tensorflow-federated
```